# Flutter compile time error. Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17)

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle, compilation

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_logs:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (17).

Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

Tried setting these inside android/app/build.gradle file:

```
android{
...
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
...
}
```